# Is my Doctrine setup properly setup for production?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have developed a website using Doctrine 2 that is now ready to go live. When I set up Doctrine in the beginning of my project I mainly worried about geting it to work, I didn't worry too much at that point about performance. Still, I don't need performance to the point on obsession, but I have a feeling that with Doctrine things can get really bad performance if it is not setup correctly. I'm thinking about the proxy classes, and I'm worried that they are generated on each call, which is not good. My code looks something like this:

```
$config=Setup::createConfiguration(FALSE);
...
$config->setProxyDir(__DIR__."/proxies");
$config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(false);
...
$em=\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($conn,$config);
```

And this works. By works, I mean that it behaves correctly. I don't think it is optimised.

From the Doctrine manual, it says about `setAutoGenerateProxyClasses`:

> Gets or sets whether proxy classes should be generated automatically at runtime by Doctrine. If set to FALSE, proxy classes must be generated manually through the doctrine command line task generate-proxies. The strongly recommended value for a production environment is FALSE.

So, the expected behaviour would be that with my setup, Doctrine should try to load the proxies from the proxies directory. I have to run the `generate-proxies` command to put them there.

The strange thing is that it works even if I don't have a proxies directory! So it seems like Doctrine is *still* generating the proxies on the fly some how. Of course, I could run `generate-proxies` and hope for the best, but I would prefer to be a bit more systematic. Is there a way to make sure that Doctrine is loading the proxies rather than generating them?

Answer (score 0):

Oops... I didn't call `$config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(false);`... The `false` came from a variable that didn't turn out to be quite `false` after all... When it actually was `false`, Doctrine refused to auto create the proxies, as would be expected. Also, there is the `orm:ensure-production-settings` command to from the cli.